# Angular ng-pdfviewer displaying pdf file in div instead of canvas

Tags: html, angularjs, html5-canvas, pdf.js

I am using [ng-pdfviewer](https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer) for displaying pdf files in webpage using angularjs.

Here the pdf file is displayed in canvas instead of div. So I can't able to view all the pages by scrolling & also I can't able to select text in the pdf.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: The source code indicates that that directive does use `canvas` tag in its template. Maybe you need another library? You need to get in touch with the author of that library who can help you better.

Comment: @Vinod, ng-pdfviewer depend on http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ and that uses canvas to Render PDF pages